# property not found an object of type

Tags: objective-c, ios

It is my first app that I am trying to build in IOS and I have some problems. Although I have read similar threads here I was not able to find the answer.

Well here are my classes:

Homeview.h

```
@interface HomeView : UIViewController{

    NSString *parsed_date;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *parsed_date;

@end
```

Homeview.m

```
@synthesize parsed_date;
parsed_date=[res objectForKey:@"date"];
```

and I want date which prints out normally in my homeview to be passed in other view.

Here are my other class:

Otherclass.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface OtherView : UIViewController{
    NSString* tracks_date;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString* tracks_date;
@end
```

Otherclass.m

```
#import "OtherView.h"
#import "HomeView.h"

@interface OtherView ()

@end

@implementation OtherView
@synthesize tracks_date;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    //preview value of other class
    NSLog(@"Dated previed in OtherView: %@", HomeView.parsed_date); //HERE IS THE ERROR
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

And here is my error:

```
property parsed_date not found on object of type "HomeView"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not using an instance of HomeView. You need to instantiate HomeView, and then you can access the property through the new instance.

It should look a bit like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    HomeView *homeView = [[HomeView alloc] init];
    homeView.parsed_date = ...assign a value to the property

    //preview value of other class
    NSLog(@"Dated previed in OtherView: %@", homeView.parsed_date); //read the value
}
```

Comment: and do I have to release it or not?

Comment: Ok now I can see its value in homeView but not in my otherView where it is null.

Comment: whether or not you have to release it depends on if you have enabled (ARC) Automatic Reference Counting or not. For iOS, I think it is enabled by default from iOS4 and upwards. If ARC is enabled then you do not need to release it manually. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: If it is null, then you have not assigned a value to the same instance that you are reading the value from.

Comment: Yes I get that. So how do I retrieve the same instance?

Comment: I have edited the response. This is a fairly fundamental programming question. I really suggest you are moving too quickly and go back to basics by following some Objective-C tutorials or reading a book. I think the original question has been answered.

Comment: well what I want is set the value of parsed_date from homeview. If it was in Java that I am familiar I would have declared it as static, assign the value in the homeview and in other view I would have written Homeview.parsed_date and I would have the value. So, in obj -c ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are really really sure, you have declared everything properly, but you keep getting "property not found", then:

**make sure all your file is in the same folder.**

Because that's what happened to me. I have two project folders, one of them for testing. I accidentally drag some files from the testing folder to my main Xcode project. It compiled ok when using only old properties, but always get a "property not found" error because the files in a testing folder cannot see new properties I've added to the main project.

Hope this helps someone in the future.